# httpモジュールのcreateServerの引数について

Tags: javascript, node.js

node.jsの勉強をしています。
httpモジュールのcreateServerの引数について質問です。
`getFormClient`関数は引数が2つありますが、
呼び出す側の`http.createServer(getFormClient)`は引数がありません。
これは、デフォルト引数ということで理解しました。

しかし、デフォルト引数であるならば、`getFormClient`関数の引数は`undefined`になり、
`res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});`などでエラーになるのではないでしょうか？

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(getFormClient)
function getFormClient(req, res){
  fs.readFile('index.html', 'UTF-8',
    (err, data) => {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: > 「引数がありません。」
「これは、デフォルト引数ということで理解しました。」

この時点ですでに理解が誤っているかと思うのですが、「何」が「何」のデフォルト引数であると判断されたのですか？また、コールバック関数の概念はご存知ですか？（なお質問のコードでデフォルト引数は関係ない気がしますが……）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> これは、デフォルト引数ということで理解しました。

いいえ、デフォルト引数ではありません。

そのコールバック関数 (`getFormClient` 関数) を呼び出すのは Node.js であり、**内部で生成されたオブジェクトを引数として、当該コールバック関数を呼び出し**ます。そのため、今回の場合デフォルト引数は関係がなく、 `getFormClient` 関数の引数は `undefined` になりません。念のため、 Node.js がどのように当該コールバック関数を呼び出すのかを、以下に粗く書いておきます。

---

`http.createServer` メソッドは、 `http.Server` クラスのインスタンスを返します<sup>[[1]](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8507485fb242dfcaf07092414871aa9c185a28e4/lib/http.js#L39)</sup>。この `http.Server` クラスは、 `requestListener` 関数 (`getFormClient` 関数) をリスナー関数として、 `request` イベントを登録します<sup>[[2]](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener)</sup>。また、この処理は以下のコードから、 `http.Server` クラスのコンストラクタで行なわれていることがわかります<sup>[[3]](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8507485fb242dfcaf07092414871aa9c185a28e4/lib/_http_server.js#L329)</sup>。

> ### node/http.js at 8507485fb242dfcaf07092414871aa9c185a28e4 · nodejs/node · GitHub<sup>[[1]](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8507485fb242dfcaf07092414871aa9c185a28e4/lib/http.js#L39)</sup>
>
> ```js
> function createServer(opts, requestListener) {
>   return new Server(opts, requestListener);
> }
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### http.createServer([options][, requestlistener])<sup>[[2]](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener)</sup>
>
> Returns a new instance of http.Server.
>
> The `requestListener` is a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event.
>
> ---
>
> ### node/_http_server.js at 8507485fb242dfcaf07092414871aa9c185a28e4 · nodejs/node · GitHub<sup>[[3]](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8507485fb242dfcaf07092414871aa9c185a28e4/lib/_http_server.js#L329)</sup>
>
> ```js
>  function Server(options, requestListener) {
>   if (!(this instanceof Server)) return new Server(options, requestListener);
>
>   if (typeof options === 'function') {
>     requestListener = options;
>     options = {};
>   } else if (options == null || typeof options === 'object') {
>     options = { ...options };
>   } else {
>     throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('options', 'object', options);
>   }
>
>   this[kIncomingMessage] = options.IncomingMessage || IncomingMessage;
>   this[kServerResponse] = options.ServerResponse || ServerResponse;
>
>   net.Server.call(this, { allowHalfOpen: true });
>
>   if (requestListener) {
>     this.on('request', requestListener);
>   }
>
>   // 省略
> ```

実際に通信が確立され、 HTTP リクエストヘッダの解析が完了すると、 `http.ServerResponse` オブジェクトが生成されます。そしてその後、  `request` イベントに登録されたリスナー関数 (`getFormClient` 関数) が、 **`http.IncomingMessage` オブジェクトと `http.ServerResponse` オブジェクトを引数として呼び出され**ます。<sup>[[4]](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/458a38c904c78b072f4b49c45dda7c63987bb60b/lib/_http_server.js#L742)</sup>。

> ### node/_http_server.js at 458a38c904c78b072f4b49c45dda7c63987bb60b · nodejs/node · GitHub<sup>[[4]](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/458a38c904c78b072f4b49c45dda7c63987bb60b/lib/_http_server.js#L742)</sup>。
>
> ```js
>   if (req.headers.expect !== undefined &&
>       (req.httpVersionMajor === 1 && req.httpVersionMinor === 1)) {
>     if (continueExpression.test(req.headers.expect)) {
>       res._expect_continue = true;
>
>       if (server.listenerCount('checkContinue') > 0) {
>         server.emit('checkContinue', req, res);
>       } else {
>         res.writeContinue();
>         server.emit('request', req, res);
>       }
>     } else if (server.listenerCount('checkExpectation') > 0) {
>       server.emit('checkExpectation', req, res);
>     } else {
>       res.writeHead(417);
>       res.end();
>     }
>   } else {
>     server.emit('request', req, res);
>   }
>   return 0;  // No special treatment.
> }
> ```